# Postgres array of custom types - how to query by custom type property

Tags: arrays, postgresql, custom-type

I want to use Postgres array to store events per each sender.
Each event is persisted as a Postgres custom type (object).

How can I query records by custom type properties? Is it possible or not?

If yes, can I put any index type on array column to speed up the queries?

Create custom type:

```sql
CREATE TYPE sender_event AS (
  event_timestamp TIMESTAMP(3),
  message TEXT
);
```

Create table with array of custom types:

```sql
CREATE TABLE sender_history (
    sender varchar(30),
    events  sender_event[]
);
```

Insert few records to the table:

```sql
INSERT INTO sender_history VALUES 
('sender1', ARRAY[(now(), 'Message text 1')::sender_event]),
('sender2', ARRAY[(now(), 'Message text 2')::sender_event])
```

How can I find all records which 'events' array contain object with "message" property equal to 'Message text 2'?

E.g. something like this (this does not work):

```sql
SELECT * FROM sender_history
WHERE events.message = 'Message text 2'
```

Expected result should be the second record in that table.

Comment: This query would be sooo much easier with a properly normalized data model.

Comment: You mean like persisting each event as a new row in a table (traditional way)? I am already doing it like this, but I want to try arrays, because the table will be smaller (faster vacuuming, less disk space required, etc...)

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: This is just an example. I have several other columns for each sender, and then I have to repeat the same value in all records, which is waste of space

Comment: No, you don't need to repeat them just create a one-to-many relationship with proper foreign keys.

Comment: Yeah, I understand... So the conclusion is that the arrays of custom objects should not be used if you need to query by custom type properties. If I don't have to query by that, then it is ok to persist data in array

Comment: Something like this: https://rextester.com/SKD98093

Answer (score 1):

You need to unnest those arrays if you want to apply a condition:

```
SELECT sh.*
FROM sender_history sh
WHERE exists (select *
              from unnest(sh.events) as x
              where x.message = 'Message text 2');
```

---

But this would be better stored in a properly normalized one-to-many relationship.

[Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html#id-1.5.7.23.8.2)

> Arrays are not sets; searching for specific array elements can be a sign of database misdesign. Consider using a separate table with a row for each item that would be an array element. This will be easier to search, and is likely to scale better for a large number of elements.

Answer (score 1):

Searching an array for a certain element you need to expand it with `unnest()` before:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=3fe9298257751046b9d2048cbce21431)

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    sender_history, 
    unnest(events) as event
WHERE event.message = 'Message text 2'
```

But nevertheless, I would really recommend to not use custom types in this case. Instead, as @a_horse_with_no_name said, you should normalize your table structure.